# using rsync to distinguish between files that are different on local vs remote vs files that exist on one but not the other

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I'm using the following command to compare directories on my local and remote machines

```
rsync -K --delete -n -avrc $cwd/* simon@${othIP}:$cwd    > /tmp/output
```

where the macros have the obvious values.

I can then parse `/tmp/output` to find which files would be deleted from the remote if I synced.

But I need to distinguish between files that

```
    - exist on the *local* but do not exist on the *remote*

    - exist on both but are different.
```

(As @BowlOfRed pointed out, the above command *does* allow me to identify files that exist on the remote but not on the local.)

Could somebody please recommend a way to do this?    Thanks very much for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that exist on the remote but not on the local will be removed and in verbose output will be shown as "deleting *filename*".

Files that exist on both but are different will be updated.  Only the filename will be displayed (without the "deleting" preceding it).

If you need to distinguish between "new" files and "updated" files, then add the -i flag.  New files will be shown with '+' for all attributes, while updated files will have specific ones show.

```
$ echo update > a/update ; echo new > a/new
$ rm a/delete_me_later
$ rsync --delete -ai a/ b/
*deleting   delete_me_later
.d..t....... ./
>f++++++++++ new
>f.st....... update
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @BowlOfRed.     I'm afraid I mis-stated my question originally.    There's a third category of files, those that exist on the local but not on the remote.   These are the ones I need to distinguish from those that exist on both but are different.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much @BowlOfRed, exactly what I wanted.    Your example was missing a few lines,   I added them in for the benefit of others.     the output for some reason is missing a line about `/` which yours had, but it does give the idea.    For anybody puzzled about the super arcane output, the posting by @mit in this site is very useful.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493525/what-does-f-mean-in-rsync-logs